# Animating UITableViewCell height and cell backgroundView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm having trouble with a custom UITableViewCell with a custom backgroundView with a custom `drawRect:`

When a user selects the cell i call

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

And returns a different height in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath`. This makes the cell animate to its new height.

All this works like a charm, but I'm having trouble with the resizing of the backgroundView. Currently the backgroundViews content stretches while the cell animates. This is not what i want and it looks horrible. I want the backgroundView to redraw its content during the animation. Is this possible, and if so, how?

I've illustrated the problem in the following image:

[image: Illustration].

**Update:**
I found out that this is what happens:

1. The cell starts out as a big cell. Everything looks good and everyone is happy.
2. The user clicks the cell.
3. The backgroundView redraws for its new height.
4. The cell animates and gets smaller. And therefore the background view is in a stretched state during the animation.

I've updated the image to reflect this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the `contentMode` of the view? It defaults to scaling behaviour. For more info, see [How to make a custom drawn UITableViewCell resize properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215891/how-to-make-a-custom-drawn-uitableviewcell-resize-properly).

Comment: Yes I've set the contentMode of both the cell and the backgroundView to UIViewContentModeRedraw, but without success.